# Getting "cat: /release: No such file or directory" when running scala

Tags: macos, scala, osx-elcapitan

I tried to install `Scala 2.12.1` on my Mac (El Capitan) via Homebrew and also by downloading the binaries from https://www.scala-lang.org/download/.

In both cases, whenever I run `scala` (or `scalac`, `scaladoc`, etc) I get this printed to screen:

```
cat: /release: No such file or directory
```

The action is successful however. E.g. `scala myscript.scala` works just fine, but that error message gets printed first.

Does anyone have an idea of why that's happening?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Opening up `bin/scala`, there's a line:

```
java_release="$(cat $JAVA_HOME/release | grep JAVA_VERSION)"
```

My `$JAVA_HOME` wasn't set. All fixed now.

Comment: It's https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10098. Regression in Scala 2.12.1, fix is already in for 2.12.2 (coming in February or thenabouts).

Comment: I faced this issue after starting to use [jenv](http://www.jenv.be/) to manage Java versions. The simplest solution in this case was to enable the export plugin for jenv via `jenv enable-plugin export` to export `$JAVA_HOME` automatically.

Answer (score 20):

I would add this as a comment but can't as of yet due to my newbie status. To specifically fix your $JAVA_HOME - if you're on UNIX you can copy and paste this in to your Terminal:

`export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"`

Replace the `1.8` with whatever version of Java you are currently working from.

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned this in my answer. I placed that in my `~/.profile` for convenience.

Comment: under Manjaro: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. In my case, `JAVA_HOME` was already set.

I got the error specifically

```
cat: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/release: No such file or directory
```

I got it fixed by creating an empty file `release` in it

```
sudo touch $JAVA_HOME/release
```

My `JAVA_HOME` looks like

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`
```

That's a hack, but it just works fine for me!

There doesn't seem to be any hard doing that also if you look at what does happen with this `/release` file while running `scala`; https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5588/files.

Caution: This solution is only applicable when you don't have `release` file in place.