# cat: /release: No such file or directory When running scala from Terminal or Scala itself

Tags: macos, scala, terminal

Yes, I know this is almost exactly the same as this question:

[Getting "cat: /release: No such file or directory" when running scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193331/getting-cat-release-no-such-file-or-directory-when-running-scala)

Well - I am brand new to submitting to SO and to Scala as well, so I wanted to ask a clarification question in the comments but can't at sub 50 reputation, so I apologize in having to pose my question here. The User answered their own question - and I needed an elaboration on what they did.

I get `cat: /release: No such file or directory` whenever I run `scalac myScalaClass.sc` or `scala myScalaClass` directly from terminal OR from when I open and run Scala from bin/scala the message appears at the top before the scripting portion opens.

Any ideas on the fix? The original OP said

`My $JAVA_HOME` wasn't set. But I'm not sure what they mean by this.

Thanks!

---

(Elaborated) Solution: 
My Java_HOME was blank, meaning it was not set properly.

Taken from the link provided in the answer by @Xander88. The checked answer there did it. All I had to do was copy and paste this in to Terminal, you can also manually copy it in to your  ~/.bash_profile :

`export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "cat: /release: No such file or directory" when running scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193331/getting-cat-release-no-such-file-or-directory-when-running-scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do this command in terminal and make sure it is set properly

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

If you don't see anything, then you have to make sure you set your path for the environmental variable $JAVA_HOME

Try referring to this article to get  you started if you are on a Mac with 10.12 Sierra.
[Where is JAVA_HOME on OSX Sierra (10.12), El Captain (10.11), Yosemite (10.10), Mavericks (10.9), Mountain Lion (10.8) or OSX Lion (10.7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/where-is-java-home-on-osx-sierra-10-12-el-captain-10-11-yosemite-10-10)

Comment: You can also try this at your own risk: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5588/files

Comment: that led me to the solution. Edited my above answer to show "step by step". Thank you.