# Scala sbt NullPointerException

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to Scala and SBT. I am getting NullPointerException please help.

.profile

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
export SPARK_HOME=/Softwares/spark
export R="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
export PATH=$PATH:$PYSPARK_PYTHON:$SPARK_HOME:$R
```

which scala

```
/usr/local/bin/scala
```

scala -version

```
cat: /release: No such file or directory
Scala code runner version 2.12.1 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.
```

which sbt

```
/usr/local/bin/sbt
```

sbt about This is sbt 0.13.13

I have created a folder FirstScala/src/main/First/First.scala containing the following

```
object First
{
    def main(args:Array[String]) {
        println("First Scala Hello World");
    }
}
```

build.sbt

```
name := "first_scala"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
```

Now in FirstScala folder I run sbt package. The .jar file gets generated.
But when I run

```
scala target/scala-2.12/first_scala_2.12-1.0.jar
```

I get the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.$anonfun$tryClass$1(ScalaClassLoader.scala:44)
at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.$anonfun$opt$1(Exception.scala:242)
at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.opt(Exception.scala:242)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.tryClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:44)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.tryToInitializeClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:40)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.tryToInitializeClass$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:40)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.tryToInitializeClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:129)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:91)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:90)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:129)
at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:21)
at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.run(MainGenericRunner.scala:13)
at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.runAndCatch(MainGenericRunner.scala:13)
at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.runJar(MainGenericRunner.scala:25)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:65)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:88)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:99)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:104)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use `sbt run` to run your code or `java` to run the .jar

Comment: This might be some OSX specific quirk, maybe try if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193331/getting-cat-release-no-such-file-or-directory-when-running-scala).

Comment: I am new to JAVA too. How do I set up JAVA_HOME. which java gives me /usr/bin/java. In .profile should I set JAVA_HOME to /usr/bin/java. Previously I set JAVA_HOME= /usr and did export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin. Then I was getting JAVA No Installed. So I removed it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the directory structure so you have `src/main/scala/First.scala`, because by default sbt expects this directory structure.
2. You need to specify the classpath and the name of the object to run (`First`).
3. Run your project using sbt:

   > ```
   > sbt run
   > [info] Loading global plugins from /dev/sw/.sbt/0.13/plugins
   > [info] Set current project to first_scala (in build file:/dev/FirstScala/)
   > [info] Running First
   > First Scala Hello World
   > [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 21, 2017 2:33:29 PM
   > ```

See an example of running the JAR using Java at http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-run-scala-sbt-packaged-jar-file-with-java-command

You can also run the JAR using Scala, but you still need to specify the classpath and object name: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-run-scala-application-jar-files-set-classpath

Comment: Actually it should work the way he set up the project, your link is about how to run Scala code with java.

Comment: I ran this
scala -classpath "target/scala-2.12/first_scala_2.12-1.0.jar" First But getting No such file or class on classpath: First I have not set JAVA_HOME is that causing all these issues

Comment: I am getting No such file or class on classpath: First

Comment: Is your object in a package? If so, you must mention the package name (`scala -classpath ... com.abilash.First`). Also: update your original post with your newest attempts

Comment: First.scala is in the following directory structure src/main/First/First.scala. First.scala contains the code I have posted above just object First {}. Could you please tell me what package should i use. I tried scala -classpath "target/scala-2.12/first_scala_2.12-1.0.jar" src.main.First also scala -classpath "target/scala-2.12/first_scala_2.12-1.0.jar" src.main.First.First same error still. Sorry for asking very basic things I am new to Scala or Java

Comment: @AbhilashDK I have reproduced your setup and made it work by changing the directory structure. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Directories.html

Comment: @radumanolescu Thank you very much for the update on folder structure. Not only I am able to run using sbt run even scala target/scala-2.12/first_scala_2.12-1.0.jar also works. Thank you again for the support :)

Answer (score 4):

export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"